# Unity WWW is deprecated. Use UnityWebRequest

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

How can I replace the `WWW` with `UnityWebRequest` in following code without breaking it?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Linq;
using System.Configuration;

public class PostNewTrackableRequest
{
    public string name;
    public float width;
    public string image;
    public string application_metadata;
}
 
public class CloudUpLoading : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    public Texture2D texture;
    
    private string access_key = "588f3c9eeb13fe81f6827cced63adca95d6a";
    private string secret_key = "77e56b7cac04b83d8ce55c13dd047e8acbbe";
    private string url = @"https://vws.vuforia.com";//@"<a href="https://vws.vuforia.com";//">https://vws.vuforia.com";</a>
    private string targetName = "Target_Hosted"; // must change when upload another Image Target, avoid same as exist Image on cloud
    
    private byte[] requestBytesArray;

    public void CallPostTarget()
    {
        StartCoroutine (PostNewTarget());
    }
    
    IEnumerator PostNewTarget()
    {
        
        string requestPath = "/targets";
        string serviceURI = url + requestPath;
        string httpAction = "POST";
        string contentType = "application/json";
        string date = string.Format("{0:r}", DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime());
    
        Debug.Log(date);
    
        // if your texture2d has RGb24 type, don't need to redraw new texture2d
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(texture.width,texture.height,TextureFormat.RGB24,false);
        tex.SetPixels(texture.GetPixels());
        tex.Apply();
        byte[] image = tex.EncodeToPNG();
    
        string metadataStr = "Target Image Detected";//May use for key,name...in game
        byte[] metadata = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(metadataStr);
        PostNewTrackableRequest model = new PostNewTrackableRequest();
        model.name = targetName;
        model.width = 64.0f; // don't need same as width of texture
        model.image = System.Convert.ToBase64String(image);
    
        model.application_metadata = System.Convert.ToBase64String(metadata);
        //string requestBody = JsonWriter.Serialize(model);
        string requestBody = JsonUtility.ToJson(model);
    
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
    
        var headers = form.headers;
        byte[] rawData = form.data;
        headers[ "host"]=url;
        headers["date"] = date;
        headers["Content-Type"]= contentType;
    
        HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(serviceURI);
    
        MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
        var contentMD5bytes = md5.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestBody));
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < contentMD5bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(contentMD5bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
        }
    
        string contentMD5 = sb.ToString();
    
        string stringToSign = string.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}", httpAction, contentMD5, contentType, date, requestPath);
    
        HMACSHA1 sha1 = new HMACSHA1(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret_key));
        byte[] sha1Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringToSign);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(sha1Bytes);
        byte[] sha1Hash = sha1.ComputeHash(stream);
        string signature = System.Convert.ToBase64String(sha1Hash);
    
        headers["Authorization"]=string.Format("VWS {0}:{1}", access_key, signature);
    
        Debug.Log("<color=green>Signature: "+signature+"</color>");
    
        WWW request =new WWW(serviceURI,System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonUtility.ToJson(model)), headers);
        yield return request;
    
        if (request.error != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("request error: " + request.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("request success");
            Debug.Log("returned data" + request.text);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I tried....but did not work. Well, obviously since I have no idea of C and I work only in Python

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Linq;
using System.Configuration;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class PostNewTrackableRequest
{
    public string name;
    public float width;
    public string image;
    public string application_metadata;
}
 
public class CloudUpLoading : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    public Texture2D texture;
    
    private string access_key = "588f3c9eeb13fe81f6827cced63adca95d6a";
    private string secret_key = "77e56b7cac04b83d8ce55c13dd047e8acbbe";
    private string url = @"https://vws.vuforia.com";//@"<a href="https://vws.vuforia.com";//">https://vws.vuforia.com";</a>
    private string targetName = "Target_Hosted"; // must change when upload another Image Target, avoid same as exist Image on cloud
    
    private byte[] requestBytesArray;

    public void CallPostTarget()
    {
        StartCoroutine (PostNewTarget());
    }
    
    IEnumerator PostNewTarget()
    {
        
        string requestPath = "/targets";
        string serviceURI = url + requestPath;
        string httpAction = "POST";
        string contentType = "application/json";
        string date = string.Format("{0:r}", DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime());
    
        Debug.Log(date);
    
        // if your texture2d has RGb24 type, don't need to redraw new texture2d
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(texture.width,texture.height,TextureFormat.RGB24,false);
        tex.SetPixels(texture.GetPixels());
        tex.Apply();
        byte[] image = tex.EncodeToPNG();
    
        string metadataStr = "Target Image Detected";//May use for key,name...in game
        byte[] metadata = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(metadataStr);
        PostNewTrackableRequest model = new PostNewTrackableRequest();
        model.name = targetName;
        model.width = 64.0f; // don't need same as width of texture
        model.image = System.Convert.ToBase64String(image);
    
        model.application_metadata = System.Convert.ToBase64String(metadata);
        //string requestBody = JsonWriter.Serialize(model);
        string requestBody = JsonUtility.ToJson(model);
    
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
    
        var headers = form.headers;
        byte[] rawData = form.data;
        headers[ "host"]=url;
        headers["date"] = date;
        headers["Content-Type"]= contentType;
    
        HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(serviceURI);
    
        MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
        var contentMD5bytes = md5.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestBody));
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < contentMD5bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(contentMD5bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
        }
    
        string contentMD5 = sb.ToString();
    
        string stringToSign = string.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}", httpAction, contentMD5, contentType, date, requestPath);
    
        HMACSHA1 sha1 = new HMACSHA1(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret_key));
        byte[] sha1Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringToSign);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(sha1Bytes);
        byte[] sha1Hash = sha1.ComputeHash(stream);
        string signature = System.Convert.ToBase64String(sha1Hash);
    
        headers["Authorization"]=string.Format("VWS {0}:{1}", access_key, signature);
    
        Debug.Log("<color=green>Signature: "+signature+"</color>");

        UnityWebRequest www =UnityWebRequest.Post(serviceURI, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonUtility.ToJson(model)), headers);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();


        if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Upload complete!");
        }
    }
}
```

This still gave me the following errors

```
Assets\Scripts\CloudUpLoading.cs(98,63): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'byte[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<UnityEngine.Networking.IMultipartFormSection>'
```

Comment: You could read the manual for starters ;P https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html

Comment: That's actually how implemented the changes. But still cannot get rid of the errors.

Comment: And which is line 98. Im not counting 98 lines

Comment: Line 98: ```UnityWebRequest www =UnityWebRequest.Post(serviceURI, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonUtility.ToJson(model)), headers);```
Total Lines: 111

Comment: I hope those access/secret keys are not actually in use.

Comment: they have been modified. They won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the headers using [SetRequestHeader](https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.SetRequestHeader.html).

```
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(serviceURI, JsonUtility.ToJson(model));

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> headerKVP in headers) {
    www.SetRequestHeader(headerKVP.Key, headerKVP.Value);
}

yield return www.SendWebRequest();
```

Comment: Tried this. Read documentation as well. But getting this error now instead  ```Assets\Scenes\CloudUpLoading.cs(100,18): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'KeyValuePair<,>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)```

Comment: @ashah `using System.Collections.Generic;`